# PHP with jQuery: how to do it in this case

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jQuery calendar with 3 event in a day. If a event booked by any client, my calendar display it booked after I submit it into a SQL database.

So if I only submit any date in SQL, my calendar display it. That means by PHP

```
if($date > 0) { echo 'here is result';}
```

For display any event I want add this below script for a particular event in my page: `{ "EventID": 1, "StartDateTime": new Date(2015,3, 1), "Title": "10am to 2pm", "URL": "username", "Description": "Booked by ", "CssClass": "Event_1" },`

Now in my SQL, I added 3 event * 31 day = 93 rows for all event. If any data find on date field in any row by id at sql, my page will be display the above script.

For more clear I give this wrong script that I want to do correctly by jQuery with PHP.

```
<?php if($id = '1'){if($date > 0){ echo' ?>
    { "EventID": 1, "StartDateTime": new Date(2015,3,<? echo '$date';?>), "Title": "10am to 2pm", "URL": "#", "Description": "Booked by ", "CssClass": "Event_1" },
<?php ';}} ?>
```

Now I cannot understand how to do it by jQuery with php? Here I read many more article but I failed.

Here is my code example:

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
global $db;
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM room ORDER BY id");
if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row['id']; 
    $date=$row['date'];
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
// others script here

 var events = [
 { "EventID": 1, "StartDateTime": new Date(2015,3, 1), "Title": "10am to 2pm", "URL": "username1", "Description": "Booked by ", "CssClass": "Event_1" },}
 { "EventID": 2, "StartDateTime": new Date(2015,3, 1), "Title": "2pm to 6pm", "URL": "username2", "Description": "Booked by ", "CssClass": "Event_2" },
 { "EventID": 3, "StartDateTime": new Date(2015,3, 1), "Title": "6pm to 10pm", "URL": "username3", "Description": "Booked by ", "CssClass": "Event_3" }
// All events
 ];
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for incorrect comment

Comment: In my practice i using Ymd format for each records and then `$array_of_records[ $Ymd ][] = ['id' => $row->id, 'name' => $row->name];`

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I made a few adjustments. I haven't tested but should work or at least point in the right direction:

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
global $db;
$result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM room ORDER BY id");
if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

$events = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if( !isset( $events[$row['date']]) ){ //create array of events for each day with results
            $events[$row['date']] = array();
        }

        $num_events = count($events[$row['date']]);
        $date = new DateTime($row['date']);

        $events[$row['date']][] = array(
            "EventID" => 1,
            "StartDateTime" => $date->format('Y-m-d'), //assuming real mysql datetime
            "Title" => "10am to 2pm",
            "URL" => "username1",
            "Description" => "Booked by ",
            "CssClass" => "Event_" . $num_events + 1 
        );
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var events = '<?php echo json_encode($events);?>' 
    for (day in events){
        var day_events = events[day];
        for(var i= 0; i< day_events.length; ++i){
            day_events[i].StartDateTime = new Date(day_events[i].StartDateTime); //convert into proper date
            console.log(day_events[i]);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```